# Unexpected results on casting betwen int and double

Tags: c

I was looking over a sample code which involved printing out the average of few numbers of the integer data type. The code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>

double getavg(int a[],int size){
    int temp=0;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        temp+=a[i];
        //checking intermediate temp
        printf("%d ",temp); 
    }
    return (temp/size);
}

int main(){
    int arr[5]={1,2,3,4,5};

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
    int avg=getavg(arr,5);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Average is %d",avg);
}
```

I tried changing the data type of temp from integer to double, and the rest of the code remaining the same, I executed the program but now the code outputs the average as 0, and also all the intermediate temp values are evaluated to zero.

```
#include<stdio.h>

double getavg(int a[],int size){
    double temp=0;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        temp+=a[i];
        //checking intermediate temp
        printf("%d ",temp); 
    }
    return (temp/size);
}
```

Can anyone please clear this ?

Comment: By evaluate to 0 do you mean printf will show 0? If yes, that's because you are using %d rather than %f.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it evaluates to double but prints an int because of the `printf` "%d" masks you are using. Use "%f" instead.

Comment: Don't worry, we all make mistakes. If the correction I suggested worked, please make sure to mark it as the right answer :)

Comment: You can find a table of the supported format strings here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf

Answer (score 0):

In order to print double you should be using `%lf` and you are using `%d` which prints integer value of your result .